# Facebook scraper doesn't load dynamic meta-tags

Tags: html, facebook, web-scraping, meta-tags, scraper

I am creating the HTML meta-tags dynamically using the function below (GWT). It takes 1 second to have this on the DOM. It is working fine except for Facebook. When I share a link from my web, the scraper gets the meta-tags that are in the HTML: none. How can I fix this?

```
/**
* Include the HTML attributes: title, description and keywords (meta tags)
*/
private void createHTMLheader(MyClass thing) {

    String title=thing.getTitle();
    String description=thing.getDescription();

    Document.get().setTitle(title);

    MetaElement metaDesc = Document.get().createMetaElement();
    metaDesc.setName("description");
    metaDesc.setContent(description);
    NodeList<Element> nodes = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head");
    nodes.getItem(0).appendChild(metaDesc);
}
```

This is the resulting HEAD on the DOM. The title **`aaaa`** and meta-description has been loaded dynamically. (Thanks CBroe for the tip). In the "view source" functionality, these dynamic tags are not displayed (only on developer tools - view dom).

```
<head>
    <title>aaaa</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta name="description" content="My description">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="dialective/dialective.nocache.js"></script><script defer="defer">dialective.onInjectionDone('dialective')</script>

</head>
```

The original HTML doesn't have a TITLE or META-DESCRIPTION tags.

Comment: Can you show the HTML this actually generates?

Comment: Thanks. Just added the <head>

Comment: Are you trying to add HTML tags with a Java app or something?  The Facebook scraper isn't going to run your Java code.  It'll see exactly what your web server is sending.

Comment: Exactly. The code below is run on client-side (a GWT presenter). So there is no way to have this done? Thanks

Comment: Nope.  Generate the meta tags on the server.

Comment: can you tell me how you solved this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Facebook scraper can only see `<meta>` tags included in the original HTML response from the server.  It's not "smart enough" to run any JavaScript code, Flash plugins, Java applets, or anything else that a full-fledged browser might run.

You'll need to generate these `<meta>` tags on the server using a server side framework.

Also, Facebook provides a handy [testing tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to make sure your page exposes the appropriate meta tags.  You might need to add OpenGraph tags as well, such as `og:title` and `og:description`.

Comment: Hi Mike, the point you made about the Facebook scraper only seeing the orig' HTML is what I've come to find as I'm having same issue as OP. However I figured what if I loaded AddThis using $.getScript after I'd made changes to the DOM. In my theory that way FB would only arrive to scrape with the new DOM. But is this not possible?

I fear that when AddThis fires and FB share is clicked the URL is passed to FB & then it does an independent scrape of the share URL which doesn't have the javascript edited meta tags. Would you have any thoughts on this? Daniel.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. What if the page is generated dynamically, like a WordPress activity post, would this then not be possible?

Answer (score -2):

> For some reason, the meta description has not been loaded with the function above...

That’s because you are only *creating* a new MetaElement – but you *do* nothing with it.

You have to *append* it to the document, more specific to its `head` element.

Something like

```
getHead().appendChild(metaDesc)
```

is missing.