# All the images are not coming from blogger in Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogger, facebook-opengraph

I have a blogger post with multiple images. All the images are uploaded from local drive. My blog post
http://canyoureadit.blogspot.in/2017/02/race-to-oscars-2017-part-2.html

I have followed the article on https://www.addthis.com/academy/how-to-add-open-graph-tags-using-blogger/ to open graph related tags.

It just adds the schema definition at the beginning and then some og tags at the head section of the template. Have not added og:image tag to each image of the post.

Now when i share the post on facebook, i only get the first image as preview. Not able to get the other images. I might be missing something here.

I have even followed this https://gist.github.com/pathawks/1343315 but getting the same results

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your blog is using a Blogger Dynamic Views template. Dynamic Views template load all the data via JavaScript (including the post HTML)

Currently, Facebook scraper doesn't run JavaScript code (Refer to [Facebook scraper doesn't load dynamic meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898673/facebook-scraper-doesnt-load-dynamic-meta-tags) ) and only infers properties from the meta tags and HTML. In your blog's case, as the post HTML is loaded via JavaScript as well, therefore, Facebook scraper only depends on the meta tags for getting information about the page. You can see a live example of what the Facebook scraper see's when parsing one of your blog post - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcodifyit.blogspot.com%2F2015%2F08%2Fcreate-your-first-php-application-with.html

To resolve this problem, switching away from Dynamic Views template to normal Blogger template would be the best solution. If you are particuarly fond of the Dynamic Views design, you can still access it while using a normal Blogger template by accessing the URL - yourblog.blogspot.com/view - For a live example, check https://blogger.googleblog.com/view

Comment: thanks Prayag for the reply...i am not using dynamic views..i am on travel template...also checked that there is no javascript in my blog...please check my blog here http://canyoureadit.blogspot.com/

Comment: I apologize for assuming the wrong blog (I picked it from your profile). In that case, you will have to add multiple og:image tags with the different Image URL. But Blogger doesn't have any layout tags for fetching the 2nd, 3rd ... etc, images . Therefore the best course of action would be remove all the og:image tags from your blog so that the Facebook scraper is forced to parse the content to find the images.